# How would I make my Python 3.6.1 Discord bot create a new text channel in a server?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been reading the documentation. The documentation shows this example:

`channel = await guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')`

I need to figure out what to do with `guild` so that there is no `NameError` regarding `guild`. (Do I have to import `guild`? etc.)

Documentations:

- http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel
- http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#guild

Comment: `create_test_channel` appears to be a method on the `Guild` class ("guild" is discord's term for a server). You need to get an instance of `Guild` first, before you can create the channel you want. The lowercase `guild` name in the example code is just a variable containing a reference to a `Guild` instance. You could use a different name if you want (and indeed, your code may already be doing so).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the rewrite branch, to create a text channel you would need to do

```
guild = ctx.message.guild
await guild.create_text_channel('cool-channel')
```

If you are using the unsupported async branch, to create a text channel you would need to do

```
server = ctx.message.server
await client.create_channel(server, 'cool-channel', type=discord.ChannelType.text)
```

If you need to figure out which branch you are using, you can do `print(discord.__version__)`. If the version is 0.16.2 or lower, then it is async. If it is 1.0.0a, then it is the rewrite

Comment: what's this "ctx" ?

Comment: @Havnar it a a parameter that you need to include in `def commandName`. I think that it needs to be the first one (except if you are including `self`)

Comment: It's tough using this library. I'm not a python efficienado and found dozens of different notations online. (as well as incompatible releases) Pycharm doesn't have intelligent/intellisens completion on the discord.py objects either. I rewrote what I had before, based on what the internet gave me to something that now has 'self' in it and now I got past this blocker.

Comment: @Havnar there are many discord libraries out there for different languages, so you are not restricted to python. If you still want to use python, you might not necessarily need to rewrite anything for this solution to work. If you are using the `async` branch (0.16.2), then this will not work for you. Also, you don't need to have the parameter be "ctx", it can be anything. I think that "ctx" is the most common, but I'm not certain

Comment: is there a way to make the channel a locked channel only the author can access it?

Comment: @AbdullahAlawad you can sort of do that. It wouldnt be completely locked because the owner (and i think admins) can access all channels, but it seems like you can set the permissions of the channel to none for everyone, and then add permissions for the author (see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#textchannel for more info on the text channel)

Comment: @qspitzer thx for the information, yes I want it like a locked help channel that only the person who ran the command and the admin able to access it

Answer (score 1):

I made my command like this, don't know if you can use it, but it works fine for me so:

```
@client.command()
async def create(ctx, *, name=None):
  guild = ctx.message.guild
  if name == None:
    await ctx.send('Sorry, but you have to insert a name. Try again, but do it like this: `>create [channel name]`')
  else:
    await guild.create_text_channel(name)
    await ctx.send(f"Created a channel named {name}")
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: `if name == None` is not recommended. Use `if name is None` instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but I wanted to answer. I was getting the error "name 'guild' is not defined". When I fixed it to "guild=message.guild" the problem went away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).