# How do I create a new private text channel and add 2 people to it?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm creating a discord bot where a user will message the bot and

1. the bot will create a new PRIVATE text channel; preferably on the same server as the bot
2. the bot will add only the messaging user and an admin to the channel

I have been able to make a new channel using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48141407/how-would-i-make-my-python-3-6-1-discord-bot-create-a-new-text-channel-in-a-serv) as a guide. I have not been able to make a private text channel or find a command that will allow me to do so. Does anyone know how to create a private text channel in discord.py and add 2 people (messaging user and an admin) to it?

Comment: By private channel, do you mean a direct message channel containing those two people, or a channel on a server that only those two can see?

Comment: A channel on a server (preferably the same one as the bot if possible) that only those two people can see. Thank you for the clarification I will edit my question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Guild.create_text_channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.create_text_channel) to create a text channel with certain permissions overwrites.  The below creates a channel that is visible only to the caller, the bot, and members with the "Admin" role (You'll need to change that to the appropriate role for your server)

```
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command()
async def make_channel(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    member = ctx.author
    admin_role = get(guild.roles, name="Admin")
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        admin_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel('secret', overwrites=overwrites)
```

Comment: Alternatively, `await channel.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, view_channel=False)` is a viable option