# How can I create private text/voice channels using discord.py?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a command to create a private text/voice channel. The problem is, I don't know how to. There are no tutorials for this on the web.
Can someone help me in how to code this?

Answer (score 0):

For this command, You are using Guild.create_text_channel

```
from discord.utils import get

@bot.command()
async def make_channel(ctx):
    guild = ctx.guild
    member = ctx.author
    admin_role = get(guild.roles, name="Admin")
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True),
        admin_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    channel = await guild.create_text_channel('secret', overwrites=overwrites)
```

If you want a more in depth answer, You can go to [How do I create a new private text channel and add 2 people to it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56241314/how-do-i-create-a-new-private-text-channel-and-add-2-people-to-it)

Comment: Thats really helpful! The problem is, that basically just dm's the user. I want to make a command that creates a private text channel in a certain discord server. Do you think you can help me in that?

Comment: Oh, Im sorry I read the question wrong! Give me one moment

Answer (score 0):

you need to **overwrite the permissions**:

```
    overwrites = {
        guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
        guild.me: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    }
    try:
        mod_logs = await guild.create_text_channel("mod-logs", overwrites=overwrites)
    except:
        print("couldn't create a mod-logs channel, maybe it exists, or the bot/user doesn't have permissions")
```

`default_role` is **@everyone**,
and `me` is the **bot** itself,